# Using config map in React JS project deployed on kubernetes

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, configmap

I building a react application and deploying it on Kubernetes. On page load i have to show certain elements and i want them to be configurable. I am driving them from json file.
I want to keep that json on config map and whenever i want to make change. Updating config map should be sufficient.

My react application is not server side application, hence not sure for approach. Is it possible to keep some file in project and then later replace it with config using docker or something.

Comment: It depends on your particular needs and your application requirements but using `ConfigMaps` seems like sensible solution. Have you already familiarized with this section in kubernetes official documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/ ?

Comment: How do you get your json file to your react App? Because if you know that, then it becomes easier to serve it to the app via a configMap.